# Make a dynamically created form visible

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that gets populated with data from Firebase. Each tr shows that data. I have dynamically created a form that gets appended to each tr, the problem is that it is not showing and I can't figure out why. I inspected each tr with the dev tools and it shows that the form with the input is indeed there but for some reason it is not visible, why? Here is my html:

```js
 const animalList = document.querySelector('#animal-list');
    const form = document.querySelector('#add-animals');
    
    
    function renderAnimals(doc) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    let name = document.createElement('div');
    let species = document.createElement('div');
    let age = document.createElement('div');
    let last_fed = document.createElement('div');
    let last_shed = document.createElement('div');
    let diet = document.createElement('div');
    let basking_area_temp = document.createElement('div');
    let cold_part_temp = document.createElement('div');
    let humidity = document.createElement('div');
    let additional_info = document.createElement('div');
    
     // The form that does not become visible

    let form = document.createElement("form");
    
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "default.aspx");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    let inputField = document.createElement("input");
    
    inputField.setAttribute("name", "firtname");
    
    inputField.setAttribute("value","product1,product2" );
    
    inputField.setAttribute("type", "text");
    form.setAttribute("class", "f")
    
    form.appendChild(inputField);
    
    tr.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    name.textContent = `name: ${doc.data().name}`
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
    deleteButton.setAttribute('class','btn btn-danger');
    species.textContent = `species: ${doc.data().species}`
    age.textContent = `age: ${doc.data().age}`
    last_fed.textContent = `last fed: ${doc.data().last_fed}`;
    last_shed.textContent = `last shed: ${doc.data().last_shed}`;
    diet.textContent = `diet: ${doc.data().diet}`;
    basking_area_temp.textContent =`basking area temp: ${ doc.data().basking_area_temp}`;
    cold_part_temp.textContent =  `cold part temp: ${doc.data().cold_part_temp}`;
    humidity.textContent = `humidity: ${doc.data().humidity}`;
    additional_info.textContent = `additional info: ${doc.data().additional_info}`;
    
    tr.appendChild(species);
    tr.append(name);
    tr.append(age);
    tr.append(last_fed);
    tr.append(last_shed);
    tr.append(diet);
    tr.append(basking_area_temp);
    tr.append(cold_part_temp);
    tr.append(humidity);
    tr.append(additional_info);
    tr.append(deleteButton);
    tr.append(form);
    
    animalList.appendChild(tr);
    
    
    //deleting data
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        db.collection('animals').doc(id).delete();
    })
    
    }
    
    // getting data from the back end
    db.collection('animals').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        changes.forEach(change => {
            if(change.type == 'added') {
                renderAnimals(change.doc);
            } else if (change.type == 'removed') {
                let li = animalList.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
                animalList.removeChild(li);
            }
        })
    })
    
    // adding data
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        db.collection('animals').add({
            species: form.species.value,
            name: form.name.value,
            age: form.age.value,
            last_fed: document.querySelector('#last-fed').value,
            last_shed: document.querySelector('#last-shed').value,
            diet: form.diet.value,
            basking_area_temp: document.querySelector('#basking-area-temperature').value,
            cold_part_temp: document.querySelector('#cold-temperature').value,
            humidity: form.humidity.value,
            additional_info: document.querySelector('#additional-info').value
    
        })
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Repti Care</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
                <h2>Add a new Animal</h2>
        <form class="form-group" id="add-animals">
        Species: <input type="text" id="species" class="form-control">
        Name: <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" >
        Age: <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control">
        Last Fed: <input type="date" id="last-fed" class="form-control">
        Last Shed: <input type="date" id="last-shed" class="form-control">
        Diet: <input type="text" id="diet" class="form-control">
        Basking area temperature: <input type="text" id="basking-area-temperature" class="form-control">
        Cold part temperature: <input type="text" id="cold-temperature" class="form-control">
        Humidity: <input type="text" id="humidity" class="form-control">
        Addition Info: <textarea class="form-control" id="additional-info"></textarea>
        <button id="btnCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
        <h3>View Current Animals</h3>
        <table id="animal-list">
         <th>Animals</th>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBSuC8nqJzLe7d5jKS-_nE15kaI9Y6NIfI",
        authDomain: "repti-care-32176.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://repti-care-32176.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "repti-care-32176",
        storageBucket: "repti-care-32176.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "632910932105"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
    </script>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <script src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is `tr.append(name);` supposed to achieve except `append is not a function` resp. `cannot call undefined as a function`?

Comment: It appends the name input field to the other form and it works fine without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're appending elements (name, age, etc.) to a `tr` element. You need to add a `td` element inside your `tr` then append to the `td`.

Solution:

After `let tr = document.createElement("tr");` add `let td = document.createElement("td");`.

Change `tr` to `td` in all 12 lines from `tr.appendChild(species);` to `tr.append(form);`.

After `td.append(form);` add `tr.appendChild(td);`

https://codepen.io/rockysims/pen/VVQmYB